# How to cancel a dragging operation in vuedraggable programmatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable

When dragging, if currently dragged element is over a (fixed) non-movable element, it should do some checking to find the closest available element to be swapped with. After that I would like to cancel the dragging even if mouse button is not released.

How to programmatically cancel the dragging when some condition is met in the `move` event ?

```
<draggable
  :list="fields"
  item-key="id"
  handle=".draggable"
  :move="draggableOnMove"
>
// template
</draggable>
```

```
const draggableOnMove = (e: any) => {
  const context = e.draggedContext;
  const related = e.relatedContext;

  // Disallow to move the fixed element
  if (related.element.value?.fixed) {
    // Swap with closest non fixed element
    let swappableIndex = context.futureIndex + 1;
    while (fields.value[swappableIndex].value?.fixed) {
      swappableIndex++;
    }
    fieldsComposable.swap(context.index, swappableIndex);

    // how to cancel a dragging here after elements has been swapped manually <----
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a variable to track whether dragging should be canceled.
2. Use the `beforeMove` event to check your condition and set the cancel flag if necessary.
3. In the `move` event, check the cancel flag, and if it's set, prevent further dragging.

Here's how you can implement this in your code:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <draggable
      :list="fields"
      item-key="id"
      handle=".draggable"
      :move="draggableOnMove"
      @beforeMove="beforeDraggableMove"
    >
      <!-- Your template content here -->
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

export default {
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [], // Your data here
      cancelDrag: false, // Flag to control dragging cancellation
    };
  },
  methods: {
    draggableOnMove(evt) {
      if (this.cancelDrag) {
        return false; // Prevent further dragging
      }
      // Your move logic here
    },
    beforeDraggableMove(evt) {
      const context = evt.draggedContext;
      const related = evt.relatedContext;

      // Disallow to move the fixed element
      if (related.element.value?.fixed) {
        // Swap with closest non-fixed element
        let swappableIndex = context.futureIndex + 1;
        while (this.fields[swappableIndex]?.fixed) {
          swappableIndex++;
        }
        // Perform the swap
        this.fields.splice(context.index, 1, this.fields[swappableIndex]);
        this.fields.splice(swappableIndex, 1, context.dragged);

        // Set the cancel flag to stop dragging
        this.cancelDrag = true;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```